# Ubuntu Desktop shows odd layout. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: ubuntu

I logged into Ubuntu and my Desktop looked like this image below and I can't do anything with it. What can I do?

[image: UbuntuDesktop]

Comment: Looks like it's set up for the wrong screen resolution. Has someone changed the display settings, installed a new graphics card or something similar? See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution about changing the resolution by editing a file.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you, that's it. It worked again by changing the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's set up for the wrong screen resolution. Has someone changed the display settings, installed a new graphics card or something similar? See [how to change the resolution](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) by editing a file.